# QGIS becomes non-responsive when adding jpg raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, error, qgis-2.12

When trying to add a raster layer (georeferenced jpg-files) QGIS becomes non-responsive. I have tested the jpgs and they are not corrupted, sometimes they appear and it works for a little while before QGIS freezes and somtimes the programme freezes while loading the images. I am using the latest version 2.12 Lyon, but had the same problem with Lisboa. My PC has 7GB ram and the jpgs are not larger than 16 to 20mb. I have loaded images in QGIS before, without problems.

Any suggestions to why QGIS becomes non-responsive?

Comment: What OS are you working on and from which source is your QGIS being installed?

Comment: Can you share a sample image or at least add what gdalinfo reports about one image?

Comment: Are you sure that your QGIS is not blocked by antyvirus/firewall or run isolated?

Comment: Do you mean you only have 7GB available RAM or just in total? Because this seems to be a very unusual amount of RAM. Most crashes/freezes have to do with RAM indeed and I would recommend checking if you are using your RAM at max cappacity.